# Environment variable $ydb_dist (/opt/yottadb/current) could not be verified against the executables path (/opt/yottadb/current/yottadb)

Tags: docker, mumps, yottadb

I'm getting this error when pulling and running the `yottadb/yottadb-debian` latest docker image. I'm using the one-liner for docker [on the vendor's site](https://yottadb.com/product/get-started/) with no success.

Is this result expected based on my warning message? Is there something I need to do differently?

```
% docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd)/ydb-data:/data yottadb/yottadb-debian:latest-master
Unable to find image 'yottadb/yottadb-debian:latest-master' locally
latest-master: Pulling from yottadb/yottadb-debian
e756f3fdd6a3: Pull complete 
46aff8aeff03: Pull complete 
85c3e3e2f9eb: Pull complete 
148d9d91d050: Pull complete 
696701bd209c: Pull complete 
650e51801ed7: Pull complete 
e152d63a4881: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:2455efef59cf561bb1b97e8ede571a0b4533390754c4fa74b51e27b41a0a18b8
Status: Downloaded newer image for yottadb/yottadb-debian:latest-master
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
Error file is at /tmp/ydb_env_1_u6fTQt/err
%YDB-E-YDBDISTUNVERIF, Environment variable $ydb_dist (/opt/yottadb/current) could not be verified against the executables path (/opt/yottadb/current/yottadb)
Sourcing /opt/yottadb/current/ydb_env_set returned status 253
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YottaDB docker images are all x86_64, and won't run on ARM64.

However, YottaDB supports ARM64 (aka AArch64) on Debian. You have to install it manually using the `ydbinstall` script. Post back if you need more help.

Comment: Hi @Sam, I do need more help. Can you be more specific about the changes I need to make exactly where?

Comment: Eric, follow the instructions here to install this on Debian AARCH64: https://yottadb.com/product/get-started/ ("Install YottaDB using the Install Script")

Answer (score 0):

YottaDB now has containers for AARCH64 as well as x86_64. See the [Get Started page](https://yottadb.com/product/get-started/).